# На устройствах с одинаковым разрешением верстка отображается по разному

Tags: android

На всех девайсах с разрешением 400х800, 480х800 планшетах вёрстка отображается правильно, но есть такой девайc **fly fs406 stratus 5** на котором нижние элементы наезжают на верхние, как будто там мало места, хотя тем не менее находятся внутри `scroll view`, на всех девайсах где не хватает всё скролится, а  на нём нет. Из-за чего такое может быть?

Корректное отображение:
[image: Как оно отображается корректно на всех девайсах]

Отображение на **fly fs406 stratus 5**: 
[image: Как оно отображается на fly]

Код разметки

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/grideperlevy">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fmt_create_cat_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@color/grideperlevy"
        android:minHeight="470dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp">

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:paddingRight="40dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="@string/add_car_to_garage"
            android:textColor="@color/slate_gray"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

        <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_pv_progress"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:pv_autostart="false"
            app:pv_circular="true"
            app:pv_progressMode="indeterminate"
            app:pv_progressStyle="@style/Material.Drawable.CircularProgress" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_car"
            theme="@style/CarCreateEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/green_jungle_krayola">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_car"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:hint="@string/car_title"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_imei"
                android:textColor="@color/slate_gray" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_imei"
            theme="@style/CarCreateEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_car"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/green_jungle_krayola">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_imei"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_car"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:hint="@string/imei"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/fmt_create_car_btn_create_car"
                android:textColor="@color/slate_gray" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            theme="@style/CarCreateEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_imei"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textColorHint="@color/green_jungle_krayola">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_phone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_et_imei"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:lines="1"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:nextFocusForward="@+id/fmt_create_car_btn_create_car"
                android:textColor="@color/slate_gray" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <com.rey.material.widget.Spinner
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_spn_beacon_type"
            style="@style/Material.Widget.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_il_phone"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:rd_style="@style/Material.Drawable.Ripple.Wave"
            app:spn_dividerColor="@color/black"
            app:spn_dividerHeight="1.3dp"
            app:spn_label="@string/beacon_type"
            app:spn_labelEnable="true"
            app:spn_labelTextColor="@color/green_jungle_krayola" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fmt_create_car_btn_create_car"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_marengo_button"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/add"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/grideperlevy"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 4):

Так чудят многие китайские и не очень аппараты. Вообще конструкция

```
<ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

давно вызывает множество вопросов. Общий итог - желательно такого избегать. Продумайте верстку, по вашим примерам не совсем понятно зачем относительное размещение, все хорошо можно скомпоновать в LinearLayout. В качестве костыля мне помогало завернуть внутренний Relative в Linear и, наплюнув на предупреждение среды о бессмысленности такой конструкции, собрать приложенько работающее на "кривых" аппаратах.
Попробуйте, может поможет и вам.

Answer (score 1):

тут из за

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
```

попробуйте добавить

```
android:layout_below="@+id/fmt_create_car_spn_beacon_type"
```